# How to watch $attrs directive, specifically $attrs.value in Vue

Tags: vue.js

How do you watch `$attrs.value` in vue?

I have a child component:

```
<custom-component v-model="someData"/>
```

Somewhere in the parent component:

```
this.$emit('input', this.dataToChild)
```

When I update `this.dataToChild` in the parent component the v-model in the child component shows the corresponding changes. However I also want changes made to `someData` in the child component to also reflect in the parent component, such that `this.dataToChild` will contain whatever `someData` has when `someData` changes. I know this change is reflected to `this.$attrs.value`. To watch for changes I know I can use `watchers` in vue.

My question is what would be the syntax to watch `this.$attrs.value`? I know to watch a prop I can just do:

```
watch: {
   propToWatch: function(newVal, oldVal) {
       this.dataToChild = newVal
   }
}
```

I also know to watch a nested prop we can:

```
watch: {
    'nested.propToWatch': function(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.dataToChild = newVal
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to watch `$attrs.value`, would it just be:

```
watch: {
    '$attrs.val': function(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.dataToChild = newVal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's just like how you would do it with a nested prop, ie:

```
watch: {
    '$attrs.value': function(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.dataToChild = newVal
    }
}
```